# How to prevent the observables from getting terminated

Tags: swift, rx-swift

```
let loadNextPageTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()

let loading = Variable<Bool>(false)


let nextPageRequest = loading.asObservable()

    .sample(loadNextPageTrigger)

    .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<Int> in

        if (loading || self.pageStatus != true || self.netStatus != true) {

            return Observable.empty()

        }
        else
        {

            return Observable<Int>.create
                { [unowned self] observer in

                    print("self.pageIndex called",self.offset)

                    self.offset += 20

                    observer.onNext(self.offset)

                    observer.onCompleted()

                    return Disposables.create()

            }

        }

}
```

on returning obervable.empty() it terminates the Observable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your code using singleton.That keeps observable which will live throughout app. use from singleton class

Answer (score 0):

You could just avoid returning an observable in that situation:

```
let nextPageRequest = loading.asObservable()

    .sample(loadNextPageTrigger)

    .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<Int> in 

            return Observable<Int>.create { [unowned self] observer in

                    print("self.pageIndex called",self.offset)

                    self.offset += 20

                    observer.onNext(self.offset)

                    observer.onCompleted()

                    return Disposables.create()

            }


}
```

Also if you need the status of that expression you could pass it as well:

let nextPageRequest = loading.asObservable()

```
    .sample(loadNextPageTrigger)

    .flatMap { [unowned self] loading -> Observable<(Bool, Int)> in 

            return Observable<(Bool, Int)>.create { [unowned self] observer in

                    print("self.pageIndex called",self.offset)

                    self.offset += 20

                    let status = loading || self.pageStatus != true || self.netStatus != true

                    observer.onNext(status, self.offset)

                    observer.onCompleted()

                    return Disposables.create()

            }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Variable is deprecated as per RxSwift v4.x
2. When something terminates unexpectedly in iOS, usually it is because it gets deallocated. If you are using DI such as Swinject, declare class containing your observable with container scope: 'container.register(MyClass.self) { _ in MyClass() }.inObjectScope(.container)'

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having has nothing to do with the code you posted. A `flatMap` will not allow a `.completed` event to escape it and that's all the `empty()` constructor emits.

In other words, returning an `.empty()` is *not* the reason your observable is terminating.